# Simpler way of installing native dependencies than Heroku buildpacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, heroku, apt-get

I have a rails app with a dependency on the `project-honeypot` gem which in turn has the following dependencies according to my `Gemfile.lock`:

```
net-dns2 
  packetfu
    network_interface
    pcarub (~> 0.12)
```

When I push to my heroku app it won't install `pcarub`. [Other sources](https://github.com/pcaprub/pcaprub/issues/9#issuecomment-12376428) lead me to the conclusion that I'm missing `libpcap` and `libpcap-devel`. I hope someone will correct me if I'm wrong here.

Unfortunately as far as I can see there is no way to run arbitrary `apt-get` commands, apart from the complexity of [heroku](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt) [buildpacks](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi). Is there any simpler solution?

Heroku / pcarub install error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pcaprub:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb

[*] Running checks for pcaprub_c code...
platform is x86_64-linux
checking for pcap_open_live() in -lpcap... no
checking for pcap_setnonblock() in -lpcap... no
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling pcaprub.c
pcaprub.c:8:18: fatal error: pcap.h: No such file or directory
 #include <pcap.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [pcaprub.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pcaprub-0.12.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pcaprub-0.12.0/ext/pcaprub_c/gem_make.out
```

Comment: You could deploy with docker. But that's not necessarily simpler. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/docker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku buildpacks turned out to be extremely simple to use. Heroku now provides [first class support for multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/653). I needed to set the ruby buildpack explicitly:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
```

Then added [heroku-buildpack-apt](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt) ahead of the ruby buildpack:

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-apt.git
```

Then my dependency in a new file called `Aptfile` in the root of my project:

```
libpcap-dev
```

The next time I deployed Heroku used the new buildpack to `apt-get install libpcap` before running bundle install.